# Dart Language: run server side application

Tags: linux, dart

I would like to know how can I run Dart applications on the server side. But I ask you to, please, read the whole question before answering it.

I know that some users already asked for something like this (or, maybe, the same thing), but I didn't find any answer useful. Well, the best one said that the "Dart VM" is inside Dart SDK. That's great! But how should I proceed? What should I do with the files? It lacks of documentation (or I'm being really blind on finding it).

The thing is: I know that Dart client side applications can be compiled to JavaScript. That's fine. I don't have any questions about it. But when we're talking about Dart server side applications (like an application with a listener), my server has to have a VIRTUAL MACHINE (as Dart documentation says).

So... **What is the procedure to install a Dart Virtual Machine on a Linux server?**

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Felipe,

I am a Dart beginner and wanted to know the answer myself. After some Googling, I found this [tutorial](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/cmdline/) that describes how to build servers that handle multiple protocols.

Quick Start: Put the ./dart-sdk/bin/ in your PATH variable and do 'dart somedartapp.dart'.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So the only thing I have to do is to place the SDK folder in my Linux server and run the Dart application there?

Comment: When you add the `dart-sdk/bin` folder to your path you can run your Dart scripts from within your Dart application folder like `dart bin/my_app.dart` (or `dart -c bin/my_app.dart` when you want to run in 'checked mode') assuming that you have your `my_app.dart` script created in `my_package/bin`.

Comment: Right. As soon as possible I will try to do it on the server and will get back to you here.